# How to click any button using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, automated-tests, qtp

I need to launch qtp.exe application using vbscipt, but im not getting the idea like how to click on certain button and how to open a particular test file using vbscript.

Please give me some hint or ideas.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily by creating COM object of QTP.

```
Dim QTPObj,QTPTest
Set QTPObj=CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")

'Check if the application is not already Launched
If Not QTPObj.Launched then
QTPObj.Launch
end if

QTPObj.Visible=True
QTPObj.Open "D:\MyQTPTests\Test1001 1001" 'name of the start up script
Set QTPTest=QTPObj.Test
QTPTest.Run 'Run the Test
QTPTest.Close 'Close the Test
QTPObj.Quit 'Quit the QTP Application
```